# Using Linq select an item outside an List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list like

```
     {
        "Nutrients": [{
            "vitamin": "vitamin C",
            "potassium": "195mg",
            "sodium": "2mg",
            "cholesterol": "",
            "display_name": "Apple"
        }, {
            "vitamin": "vitamin B",
            "potassium": "176mg",
            "sodium": "2mg",
            "cholesterol": "",
            "display_name": "Grape"
        }],
        "General_name": "Fruits",
        "country_of_origin": "France"


     }


     {
        "Nutrients": [{
            "vitamin": "vitamin B",
            "potassium": "196mg",
            "sodium": "115mg",
            "cholesterol": "123mg",
            "display_name": "Chicken"

        }, {
            "vitamin": "vitamin B",
            "potassium": "360mg",
            "sodium": "53mg",
            "cholesterol": "68mg",
            "display_name": "Chicken"
        }],
        "General_name": "Meat",
        "country_of_origin": "Denmark"

     }
```

And I need to find the General_name of items which have empty string value for cholesterol.

I tried it using linq lambda expression as

```
var elements=items.SelectMany(c =>c.Nutrients)
    .Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.cholesterol))
    .ToList();
```

My question is how to get the general name from this condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var elements = items.Where(x => x.Nutrients.Any(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.cholesterol)))
   .Select(x => x.GeneralName)
   .ToList();
```

This will get you a list of all the GeneralName values where the containing Nutrients collection contains a non empty value for cholesterol. Is that what you are looking for?

---

Edit:

> Is there a way I can get the display_name of those items as well?

```
var elements = items.Where(x => x.Nutrients.Any(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Cholesterol)))
    .Select(x => new {x.GeneralName, DisplayNames = x.Nutrients.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Cholesterol)).Select(y => y.DisplayName).ToList()})
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot the bool option.Thanks

Comment: @Mithun - Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)) once the 15 minutes period has expired.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the display_name of those items as well?